# CSS specificity, id vs class

Tags: css

If id's are weighted higher than class, then why does the class c2 style take precedence over the style of the div which is specified by id?

```css
.c2 {
  color: red;
}

#id1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol id="id1">
  <li class="c2">test</li>
  <li class="c3">test2</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While an ID selector does indeed provide more **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** than a class selector in CSS, that's not actually what's going on here, as the two rules aren't targeting the same element. What you're actually dealing with is a class selector that targets an element versus a style that is [**inherited**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

`.c3` has no rule that targets it directly, but inherits the parent colour from `#id1`, thus it is blue. Conversely, `.c2` inherits the parent colour, and then has the class selector apply to it, **overriding** the inheritance, and causing it to be red:

```css
.c2 {
  color: red;
}

#id1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <li class="c2">test</li>
  <li class="c3">test2</li>
</div>
```

As **[MDN state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance#Inheritance)**:

> It makes sense for font-family and color to be inherited, as that makes it easy for you to set a site-wide base font by applying a font-family to the  element; you can then override the fonts on individual elements where needed. It would be really annoying to have to set the base font separately on every element.

You can also actually prevent this inheritance if you want with `color: initial`:

```css
#id1 {
  color: blue;
}

.c2 {
  color: red;
}

.c3 {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <li class="c2">test</li>
  <li class="c3">test2</li>
  <li class="c4">test3</li>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)